# Radio Button - Save selected values as numbers

Tags: radio-button, xpages

I got a radio button control with two different choices: "Ja" and "Nein". In the background the values 1 and 0 should be saved as numbers. But this does not work, because as soon as I choose one value and save the document (e.g. I've selected "Ja"|1) the value gets converted into boolean and true is saved instead of 1.

```
<xp:radioGroup id="rbgIsEmployed" value="#{docApplication.IsEmployed}">
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Ja" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Nein" itemValue="0"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:radioGroup>
```

What do I have to do to save numeric values instead of boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a number converter and set itemValues as numbers:

```
<xp:radioGroup id="rbgIsEmployed" value="#{docApplication.IsEmployed}">
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Ja"
        itemValue="${javascript:1}"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Nein"
        itemValue="${javascript:0}"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber
            type="number"
            integerOnly="true"></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:radioGroup>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Still only boolean values are saved and on the xpage the displayed value (the document has saved the value 1) is 1 and not "Ja"

Comment: It does work in my test. Is `docApplication.IsEmployed` a number field in document or a java bean property of type `boolean`? I tested with document's number field

Comment: This field is defined as number in the form

Comment: What do you mean by "only boolean values are saved"? There is no boolean field type in Notes. Did you try my original code in your XPage?

Comment: How does field `IsEmployed` in saved document looks like? With the code in my example it should be: Field Name=IsEmployed, Data Type=Number, Data Length=8 bytes and contain value 0 or 1. Maybe you have some other code which is changing the field?

Comment: Your solution worked. Just found another piece of code changing the field value... thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad we finally found the solution for your application.